# SQL job agent SSIS package configuration

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job

I have an SSIS package deployed to sql server, running on a scheduled job.  In the job properties Steps, I go to the Configuration tab and see my Parameters:

[image: Configuration]

The UploadFTPSSHKey variable is giving me problems.  With the particular library I'm using, passing in an invalid ssh key results in an exception being thrown.  If I hardcode it or pass it in as a local variable it works fine.  The other parameters are working correctly as well, so I'm guessing that the problem is related to the spaces in the ssh key?  I've tried using quotes, double quotes, no quotes... no luck in any case.  Any idea about how I can make this parameter work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I don't know why it's happening, but I put a line in a script task that simply wrote the value of the variable out to a file and it looked like this:  ssh-rsa "2048" 82:2b:etc.  For some reason, it puts only the 2048 in double quotes.  I fixed the problem by just hacking in a string replace before passing the fingerprint to my sftp library.